# Service Manual For Rodgers 770

Tags: instruments, organ

TLDR: **Where can I find the service manual for the Rodgers Exeter 770 pipe organ?**

I am trying to repair a Rodgers Exeter 770 digital pipe organ, however, I do not have the service manual. I easily found online copies of the owner's manual (like [this one](https://www.frogmusic.com/owners-manuals/770770-pipe-augmented.pdf)), but it does not contain any of the schematics or wiring diagrams-which I need.

It has been over 3 weeks ago since I emailed and called Rodgers Instruments (the company which made the organ) asking for a copy, but I have not heard back.

If there is a Stack Exchange site better suited for this question, let me know, and I'll post there.

Comment: Strictly speaking, resource requests like this are "off-topic" here; however, is there a specific piece of information you need, or instructions for a particular procedure? Those are questions we address.

Comment: They ended up responding and sent the service manuals (apparently there are 2). In case anyone else needs them, and since they don't appear to exist on the internet, I have uploaded them to [MediaFire](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/5tq1upzqyw1si/Rodgers_Exeter_770_Service_Manual), [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TBIXp6Tm0g2VcnJ9HAwQlWo04pVo2ZWl?usp=sharing), and [GitHub](https://github.com/Thoughtyness/Rodgers-Exeter-770). If all three links go down, reply and I'll reupload.